# php preg_replace phone number with spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following code that finds a number in a string and makes it bold.  However, if there are spaces in the phone number the b tags get added multiple times. What do I need to amend to allow spaces to be anywhere within the phone number?

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\d+)/', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

Comment: You mean you have spaces *inside* digits? Try `'/(\d+(?:\s+\d+)*)/'` or `'/([\d\s]+)/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Regex:

```
(\d[\d\s]*)(?=\s+)
```

How it works:

```
(
  \d             # First digit
  [\d\s]*        # Any more digits or whitespace
)
(?=\s+)          # To make sure not to Capture last whitespace
```

It will not capture the last space, so rather than ending up with `<b> 123 </b>`, you will end up with `<b>123</b>`

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/dY2aH8/1)</kbd>

[image: Demo]

---

This RegEx will also work:

```
/([\d\s]+)/
```

However, this will match the string if there are no digits, only spaces.

Comment: I have just realised that this isn't working correctly.  If I have the following string:  "Call us on 0800 2478 564 now!"  I get the following output:  "Call us on <b>0800 2478</b> 564 now!"  Therefore not all of the phone number is wrapped in bold tags.  What do I need to change please?

Comment: @LeeTee [It does work, see?](https://regex101.com/r/iG7yN6/1) And what output do you get, you comment is blank. Maybe surround the code in `\``

Comment: I accidently posted it too soon so had to go back and edit.

Comment: The only difference I can see with the regex in regex101 and my code is it has /g at the end.  Is this what Im missing? from the code?  Should it be:  /(\d[\d\s]*)(?=\s+)/g  instead of : /(\d[\d\s]*)(?=\s+)/   ?

Comment: Ive just realised it does work but not if the number is at the end of the sentence.  eg.  Call us now on <b>0800 2478</b> 564

Comment: Just change `(\d[\d\s]*)(?=\s+)` to `(\d[\d\s]*)(?=\s+|$)` (Add `|$` in the lookahead to select the end of the line / string)